# Google Chrome when inactive but visible, on Mac, always requires at least two clicks to follow links

Tags: macos, google-chrome

If I'm working on another application and Google Chrome window is visible on the side and I see a link that I want to follow, the first click doesn't press the link. It activates the Google Chrome window. Only after activating Chrome can I now follow links and interact with the web page.

Other Mac apps don't behave like this. Even if the app isn't active, if you can see it and click some where, the click executes just as if the app was active.

This is annoying in Chrome for Mac. I'm pretty sure it wasn't like this on Windows.

Is there anyway to fix it?

Comment: What version of OS X are you running?  I'm on 10.8, and in this version and every other one I can remember, if the target of your click isn't the current window, it takes one click to bring to the front and make it active, then a second click to activate a control on the window. I can definitely hover over an inactive window and scroll it, but to interact with it otherwise I need to click on it to make it active.

Comment: @Eric I'm on Mavericks. It's my first OS X. The behavior is different from what you're describing, even in Finder and the Messages apps. For instance, Finder is inactive but its back button is visible. It takes only one click on the back button to work.

Comment: yeah it does this with safari and firefox as well. Super annoying.

Answer (score 1):

I have this 'feature' or process to be super annoying as well.  I just figured out that if you hold the command button as you click the first link (while chrome window is visible but not active) the initial link you click will open on first click.

I'm a new macbook user and windows didn't have the same issue with opening links on chrome on inactive windows.  hope this helps!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1108810)

Answer (score -1):

The behavior you described is purposeful - both from Mac OS X and Chrome.

Some more details in https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/34446/enable-click-through-preferrably-for-all-applications

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.  Note: *Your answer came to my attention due to another low quality answer submitted to this question.*